# Looking for informed people to evaluate a creative writing project about psychiatry

Tags: fantasy, science-fiction, research, beta-readers

I am a beginning writer.  I would like to write a science fiction / fantasy book that is critical of psychiatry, including diagnosis inflation, the influence of Big Pharma, and the field's de-emphasis of spiritual concerns as biochemical imbalances.

Although it may require research, my fictional story must let the research "play out" through standard literary devices such as setting, characters, plot, theme, voice, etc. instead of lectures or preaching. However, although I can take a poetic license, I want my ideas to be also somewhat grounded in fact, because my goal is to explore the above issues.

I would like to show the full scope of my project in this post, but I fear that it would be too involved.  Suffice to say, my story will touch on a number of disciplines, including medicine or psychiatry, psychology, psychotherapy or counseling, sociology, political science, and spirituality or religion, among others.

I am looking for informed people to evaluate my writing, either as I produce chapters (my preference right now), or at the end of the process.  This support could be beta reading or something else.  How would I advertise for or seek this support?

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Critique Circle](http://www.critiquecircle.com/), which is a free online critiquing community. (I haven't used it, but others here have.)

If you have enough rep, you could ask in our Chat Room, [the Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel). There are a number of members here who are freelance editors who might be able to work with you.